# Linkedin api oauth2.0 get user profile details

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

As per the new oauth 2.0 for linkedin.
I am unable to get user profile details.
I have set the attributes in my app but still cant get the details.

Can somebody help me the code snippet to get user details.

```
    public function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . 
            $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] . "\r\n" . 
            "x-li-format: json\r\n"
        )
    );

    $url = 'api.linkedin.com' . $resource;
    if (count($this->$params)) {
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($this->$params);
    }
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return json_decode($response);
}


$xml_response = $LinkedInn->fetch("GET","/v1/people/~");
```

Comment: What is the response you're getting back?

Comment: Blank response....nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permissions in your code when you are logging in with linked-in.
Look at this link-

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition